# перебор элементов объекта с помощью jQuery $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Необходимо получить данные из filename, raw_url и language. JS начал изучать вчера, нужна критика.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/gists/public', function (data) {
            var gist_data = "";
            $.each(data, function (key1, data1) {
                $.each(data1, function (key2, data2) {
                    if (key2 == "files") {
                        $.each(data2, function (key, value) {
                            console.log(key, value)
                            gist_data += '<tr>';
                            gist_data += '<td>' + value['filename'] + '</td>';
                            gist_data += '<td>' + value['language'] + '</td>';
                            gist_data += '<td><a href="">' + value['raw_url'] + '</a></td>';
                            gist_data += '</tr>'
                        })
                    }
                })
            });
            $('#gist_table').append(gist_data)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: структуру json добавте чтоли

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, структура [по ссылке](https://api.github.com/gists/public). 
А ТС, похоже, что "курс молодого бойца" по JS не прошёл. Вы работаете не c `JSON` и даже не со строкой в формате `JSON`, а с объектом. Если вы не знаете, что это и с чем его едят, то [рекомендую познакомиться](https://learn.javascript.ru/object).

Comment: Данные необходимо брать от сюда: https://api.github.com/gists/public

Comment: Методом проб и ошибок написал следующее. Нужна критика =)